# R: How to order every two rows in data.table/data.frame by specific column/variable?

Tags: r, sorting, datatable

I have a `datatable` and would like to `order` every each two rows by a specific column. this mean order compare rows 1,2 and order based on column x and then the same for row 3,4 and 5,6 and etc.

For example, I'd like to order `every two rows` in `df` based on `ID` column :

```
library(data.table)
ID <- c("229-220", "229-27", "229-321", "229-36")
Var1 <- LETTERS[1:4]
df<- data.frame(ID, Var1)
setDT(df)

 df
       ID  Var1
1 229-220    A
2 229-27     B
3 229-321    C
4 229-36     D
```

Expected results:

```
      ID    Var1
1  229-27    B
2  229-220   A
3  229-36    D
4  229-321   C
```

I tried `df[order(ID)]` which dose not help!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can find something better, but this should work... I assume you want to sort Z to A, right?

```
my.ord <- do.call(c, lapply(seq(2, nrow(df), by = 2), (function(i){
  c(i-1, i)[order(df$ID[(i-1):i], decreasing = T)]
})))
df <- data.frame(df[my.ord,], row.names = NULL)
```

Result

```
df
       ID Var1
1 229-220    A
2  229-27    B
3 229-321    C
4  229-36    D
```